# React Native - Listview pull down to refresh fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, ajax, listview, react-native

I am trying to use the onScroll function for ListView to check when a user has pulled the list down past a certain pixel value to trigger an  AJAX call and refresh the list. However it fires multiple times resulting in a jerky animation of the Activity Indicator.

Seems to happen because `e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y < -50` is being checked so frequently during the pull down and release. Is there a better way to do a pull down refresh in ListView or a way to handle the spinner better? Thanks

```
  _handleScrollView(e) {
    if (e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y < -50 && !this.props.listingsLoading) {
      // sets listsLoading to false when complete
      this.props.fetchListings()
    }
  }

  _renderLoadingView() {
    if (this.props.listingsLoading) {
      return (
         <ActivityIndicatorIOS />
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    var listings = this.state.dataSource

    return (
      <View>
        {this._renderLoadingView()}
        <ListView
          onScroll={this._handleScrollView}
          dataSource={listings}
          renderRow={this._renderRow} />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

EDIT: I added the following to get it working using RefreshControl, Thanks David!

```
            <ListView
              refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl
                  refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
                  onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
                  tintColor="#ff0000"
                  colors={['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']}
                  progressBackgroundColor="#ffff00"
                />
              }
              dataSource={listings}
              renderRow={this._renderRow}/>
```

Then defined an onRefresh function:

```
  _onRefresh() {
    this.setState({isRefreshing: true});
    this.props.fetchListings(this.props.nextPage)
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        isRefreshing: false
      });
    }, 3000);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the build-in [Refresh Control](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html) for pull to refresh functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, does Refresh Control work just for ScrollView or will it also work for ListView?

Comment: Just tested and it works beautifully. Thanks so much! Wish they had included that in the description for ListView in the docs